How to visualize attention weighted feature map of BiLSTM seq2seq model using 3-dimensional temporal data?
I'm developing an attention-based BiLSTM seq2seq model for time series forecasting. My dataset has 3-dimension shape (None, 4, 67). The None means a number of samples and the 4 presents time steps. Also, the 67 indicates a number of features. Then, I implemented encoder and decoder strutures using two BiLSTM layers. The attention layer was located between two BiLSTM layers.
input_emr = Input(shape = (length_thres, x_train.shape[2]))

x = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, 
                       input_shape=(length_thres, 50), 
                           return_sequences=True, 
                           return_state=False))(input_emr)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, 
                           return_sequences=True))(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
#x = SeqSelfAttention()(x)
x = AttentionWithContext()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)

#out = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
out = Activation('relu')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_emr, outputs=out)

model.compile(
    #loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), 
    loss = 'mse',
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3), #'sgd'
    metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error'],
   # metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()]
)
print(x_train.shape[2])
model.summary()```


The model summary is below.
The model architecture is below
Also, the code of attention layer is below.
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.layers import \*
from keras.models import \*
from keras.callbacks import \*
from keras.optimizers import \*
from keras.metrics import \*
from keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints, losses
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
#from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K

def dot_product(x, kernel):
if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
return K.squeeze(K.dot(x, K.expand_dims(kernel)), axis=-1)
else:
return K.dot(x, kernel)

class AttentionWithContext(Layer):
def __init__(self,
W_regularizer=None, u_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
W_constraint=None, u_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
bias=True, \*\*kwargs):
self.supports_masking = True
self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
self.u_regularizer = regularizers.get(u_regularizer)
self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
self.u_constraint = constraints.get(u_constraint)
self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)
self.bias = bias
super(AttentionWithContext, self).__init__(\*\*kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
    
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'W_regularizer': self.W_regularizer,
            'u_regularizer': self.u_regularizer,
            'b_regularizer': self.b_regularizer,
            'W_constraint': self.W_constraint,
            'u_constraint': self.u_constraint,
            'b_constraint': self.b_constraint,
            'bias': self.bias,
        })
        return config
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
            self.u = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_u'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.u_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.u_constraint)
        super(AttentionWithContext, self).build(input_shape)
    
    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        return None
    
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        uit = dot_product(x, self.W)
        if self.bias:
            uit += self.b
        uit = K.tanh(uit)
        ait = dot_product(uit, self.u)
        a = K.exp(ait)
        if mask is not None:
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]

I want to visualize a feature importance in individual-level using attention layer like these two pictures.
1. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046421002057#f0020
2. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0211057
Specifically, I want to show four attention-wegited 67 features map in one sample.
Despite I tried to get the attention weights, I couldn't calculate a matrix multiplication of attention weights and feature because a number of the model neurons was 100 and a number of features was 67.

Please don't give image.
